# Netbeans 7.2 Ctrl + click doesn't open

Tags: netbeans-7.2

I recently installed netbeans 7.2 it was installed successfully but when iam opening it displays like loading cached objects and it is closing

Comment: https://www.quora.com/NetBeans-7-2-isnt-starting-up-on-my-Windows-8-It-just-closes-after-the-blue-loading-screen-It-shows-Loading-cached-objects-but-after-5-seconds-it-just-closes-What-should-I-do

Answer (score 0):

Please use an up-to-date version of NetBeans! 7.2 is quite old. 8.1 is the current stable version. And try it again.